# Powershell and Webservices: One of the parameters is a DateTime... How can I pass that value?

Tags: powershell, web-services, datetime

Through PowerShell I am calling a SOA Service. The call is OK except for one field which is a DateField

```
$dataTeste = '09-JAN-18'
$dataTeste = [datetime]::ParseExact($dataTeste, "dd-MMM-yy", $null)
$dataTesteSeg = $dataTeste.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")

$dataTesteSeg | Out-File -FilePath C:\temp\testefileseg.txt -Append

$posTangivelGerarReqAud.idSistemaOrigem = "PowerShell"  
$posTangivelGerarReqAud.idUtilizador = "user186"
$posTangivelGerarReqAud.tsInvocacao = $dataTesteSeg
$posTangivelGerarReqGen.idDocumento = "DRU_0012"
$posTangivelGerarReqGen.tipoEvento = "E"

$posTangivelGerarReqAud.tsInvocacao | Out-File -FilePath C:\temp\testefile.txt -Append
```

So, to debug the process, I wrote the variable to log files, so I can tell you that $dataTesteSeg has the value of "2018-01-09" which is the value I pretend to pass to the webservice, however, after I associate the variable the webservice parameter, it becomes different. 
On the debug file $posTangivelGerarReqAud.tsInvocacao becomes "Tuesday, January 9, 2018 12:00:00 AM". How can I force the webservice field to be on the format "yyyy-MM-dd".

Thanks!

Comment: Looks like the `$posTangivelGerarReqAud.tsInvocacao` element is a `DateTime]` object and the string you are assigning ("2018-01-09") gets parsed into a real date. Then on output, the localized `.ToString()` is called, which happens to format as "dddd, MMM d, yyyy HH:mm:ss tt". If possible, have the `tsInvocacao` element be a String, not a DateTime so the format won't change.

Answer (score 0):

Try

`$dataTesteSeg = Get-Date $dataTeste -UFormat '%Y-%m-%d'`

See `Get-Help Get-Date -Full` for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
get-date $posTangivelGerarReqAud.tsInvocacao -Format "yyyy-MM-dd"
```

Comment: It works if I want to write an output for example but I even tried  $posTangivelGerarReqAud.tsInvocacao = get-date $posTangivelGerarReqAud.tsInvocacao -Format "yyyy-MM-dd" and it still doesn't work. It stays with the format I do not pretend

Answer (score 0):

When you line below runs you are assigning a date to a DateTime Object.

```
$posTangivelGerarReqAud.tsInvocacao = $dataTesteSeg
```

When you run the lines below it outputs in its default DateTime format.

```
$posTangivelGerarReqAud.tsInvocacao
Get-date
[datetime]::now
```

It is up to you to convert the DateTime object into to the format you want.

```
get-date $posTangivelGerarReqAud.tsInvocacao -Format "yyyy-MM-dd"
get-date -Format "yyyy-MM-dd"
```

I hope code below jump starts your project.

```
$dataTeste = '09-JAN-18'
$dataTeste = [datetime]::ParseExact($dataTeste, "dd-MMM-yy", $null)
$dataTesteSeg = $dataTeste.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")

$posTangivelGerarReqAud.idSistemaOrigem = "PowerShell"  
$posTangivelGerarReqAud.idUtilizador = "user186"
$posTangivelGerarReqAud.tsInvocacao = $dataTesteSeg
$posTangivelGerarReqGen.idDocumento = "DRU_0012"
$posTangivelGerarReqGen.tipoEvento = "E"


$myObject = [PSCustomObject]@{
    idSistemaOrigem     = $($posTangivelGerarReqAud.idSistemaOrigem)
    idUtilizador        = $($posTangivelGerarReqAud.idUtilizador)
    tsInvocacao         = $(get-date $posTangivelGerarReqAud.tsInvocacao -Format "yyyy-MM-dd")
    idDocumento         = $($posTangivelGerarReqGen.idDocumento)
    tipoEvento          = $($posTangivelGerarReqGen.tipoEvento)

} 

$myObject | Out-File -FilePath C:\temp\testefile.txt -Append
```